# kill file that is currently locked (without admin rights)

Tags: vba, ms-access, powershell, ms-office

I want to use VBA or PowerShell to kill files that are currently locked (because another user has it open).

Is there a way to do this even if I don't have admin rights? Any 1337 hackers out there who can help me?

Here's the basic setup in VBA, but right now I'm getting a `permission denied` error when I try killing a file that is open.

```
Function fn_testKILL()

    'load INI data
    fn_ReadINI


    'read files from iDumpFolder
    Dim fs          As Object
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim objFolder   As Object
    Set objFolder = fs.GetFolder(iDumpFolder)
    Dim objFile     As Object

    For Each objFile In objFolder.files
        ' is the file open? if yes, kill file.
        If Not FileLocked(objFolder & "\" & objFile.Name) Then
            'file is locked
            'do nothing
        Else
            'file is locked
            Kill objFile
            'or if this is not possible with VBA, trigger PS1 execution
        End If

    Next 'objFile

    'Cleanup
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by `kill` you mean you want to delete a locked file, you are out of luck. One of the basic raison d'etres of an operating system is to prevent user A messing with user B's stuff.

If you do have permissions, you could terminate the process or file handle that locks the file. Take a look at [Sysinternals' toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals). `Handle.exe` can be used to close file handles.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have admin privileges on the server. Is there no sneaky way to circumvent security?

Comment: @sion_corn Yes, all general purpose OS have security vulnerabilities that could be of use. Are you aware that circumventing those is often illegal and you can be fired from doing such a thing? You are not going to get much black hat hacking help from SO anyway.

Comment: fair point. i suppose it isn't worth forcing it. *but it would be so cool if i could...*